# How to control or customise named route Rails's link_to() uses for a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a namespaced model and controller:

```
# app/controllers/foo_stuff/bars_controller.rb
module FooStuff
  class BarsController < ApplicationController
    # ..
  end
end

# app/models/foo_stuff/bar.rb
module FooStuff
  class Bar < ApplicationRecord
    # ...
  end
end
```

I want:

- URLs to look like `/foo/1`, which would route to `FooStuff::BarController#show`.
- Named route helpers to look like `foo_url`, e.g. `foo_url(@bar)`.

I have my routes set up like this:

```
# config/routes.rb
scope module: 'foo_stuff', as: 'foo' do
  resources :bars, path: 'foo'
end
```

This looks correct when I run `rails routes`.

However, when I try:

```
<%= link_to('Something', @bar) %>
```

...Rails complains of `undefined method 'foo_stuff_bar_url' for an instance of #<Class:...>`.

It's fine if I explicitly use the named route:

```
<%= link_to('Something', foo_url(@bar) %>
```

I expected that `link_to()` would figure out from the routes what named route helper to call for a `@bar` model.  But it doesn't.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way model is mapped to a path is basically this:

```rb
send("#{FooStuff::Bar.model_name.route_key}_path")
```

You can change how a particular model routes are resolved, aka change its [polymorhpic](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html#method-i-polymorphic_url) url mapping, with [`resolve`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/CustomUrls.html#method-i-resolve):

```rb
# config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope module: "foo_stuff", as: "foo" do
    resources :bars, path: "foo"
  end

  resolve "FooStuff::Bar" do |bar|
    if bar.persisted?
      [:foo_bar, id: bar.id]
    else
      [:foo_bars]
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
<%= link_to nil, FooStuff::Bar.first %>
#=> <a href="/foo/1">/foo/1</a>

<%= link_to nil, FooStuff::Bar.new %>
#=> <a href="/foo">/foo</a>
```

---

However `resolve` doesn't work for everything:

```rb
<%= link_to nil, [:edit, FooStuff::Bar.first] %>
#=> undefined method `edit_foo_stuff_bar_path'
```

You could "solve" that too with [`direct`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/CustomUrls.html#method-i-direct), which is more like making an alias to the correct route:

```rb
# config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # ...

  direct :edit_foo_stuff_bar do |bar|
    [:edit, :foo_bar, id: bar.id]
  end
end
```

```rb
<%= link_to nil, [:edit, FooStuff::Bar.first] %>
#=> <a href="/foo/1/edit">/foo/1/edit</a>
```

---

Finally, you could change the route keys, any side effects are on you:

```rb
FooStuff::Bar.model_name.route_key = "foo_bars"
FooStuff::Bar.model_name.singular_route_key = "foo_bar"
```

```rb
<%= link_to nil, FooStuff::Bar.first %>          #=> <a href="/foo/1">/foo/1</a>
<%= link_to nil, FooStuff::Bar.new %>            #=> <a href="/foo">/foo</a>
<%= link_to nil, [:edit, FooStuff::Bar.first] %> #=> <a href="/foo/1/edit">/foo/1/edit</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining all that.  `resolve` does exactly what I need.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The shorthand version of `link_to` will only look for the conventional path helper name based on the `.class` of the object you pass in. It has no way to know that the `@bar` object, or the `FooStuff::Bar` class should be linked to that particular route. Think about it, it's not like you associate the **model** class with that route in any way.